# Determine the number of combinations possible?

Tags: calculus, statistics

I am trying to determine the number of possibilities in a series of drop down boxes. I have 8 drop down boxes each of which a drop down box can be either selected or not selected (2 options). If I am trying to determine how many combinations there could be (between selected and not selected) Would the number of total possible combinations be 2^8 or 256? If so, could you explain.

Thank you!

Comment: How did you arrive at the number 256?

Comment: 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 x 2. However, I am not certain that is the correct answer.

Comment: It is correct..

Comment: Thanks. And, that would work the same if there were 3 options x 8 boxes or 3 x 3 x 3 x 3 x 3 x 3 x 3 x 3 = 6561 or any combination of numbers I suppose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $2$ possibilities for each box. Since there are $8$ boxes in series the cases get multiplied and you get $2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2=256$ combinations.

For better understanding, suppose there were $2$ boxes.

Then possible combinations would be $ \{S_1S_2, S_1N_2, N_1S_2, N_1N_2 \}$ where $S_i$ means $i^{th}$ box is selected and $N_i$ means $i^{th}$ box is not selected. Hence you get $2*2=4$ possible cases.

Your $3$ options and $8$ boxes case is also correct.